# Failed to contact master failure by starting turtlesim

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together,

follwing failure message occurs by starting turtlesim:

> faps@UbuntuBioMech:~$ rosrun turtlesim
> turtlesim_node [ERROR]
> [1345405836.027275917]:
> [registerPublisher] Failed to contact
> master at [localhost:11311].
> Retrying...

Any Suggestions?
Many thanks in advance,
Dominik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41813/failed-to-contact-master-failure-by-starting-turtlesim/) by [rosrookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3050/rosrookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2012-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to run roscore in another terminal.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4